# What GPU parameters show me what video card have faster convert speed?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, conversion, speed

I want to crop videos in Avidemux, and I search a cheap used videocard for faster coding. But I can't compare because I don't know what parameters need to be higher or lower for faster video coding.

I have Intel® UHD Graphics 630 and PNY K420. In Avidemux was the nvidia h264 also before I installed Cuda tools, so I don't know what doing the CUDA Tools. But I haven't VCE/VCN in the list but the K420 datasheet say that also OpenCL. And somebody looked today the Avidemux with 6600XT, and also wasn't in the list. But I was thinking about an RX580.

I was think also parameters like Texture fill rate, floating point performance and what I found on the compare websites.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most video cards in a generation are going to have identical (or at least reasonably similar) encode speeds.

Video encoding is not done based on the amount of stream processors, instead it is done using fixed function encode blocks.

For Nvidia it that block is known as is as [NVENC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_NVENC#Versions), Intel has [Quicksync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video) and AMD have their [Video Coding Engine (VCE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Coding_Engine)

Because these are fixed blocks of silicon, likely operating at fixed speeds on all cards, they will perform roughly the same among a series. A newer generation may perform somewhat better than an older generation, but as they are all aiming to be able to encode at a specific rate (likely 4K @ 60Hz) they are unlikely to be significant leaps in performance.

Also, while some Nvidia cards have 2 NVENC units these are more for simultaneous encodes and will not see a significant boost to single stream encode speed.

Answer (score 0):

**CUDA or OpenCL Support**

Avidemux supports GPU acceleration through CUDA and OpenCL (for NVIDIA GPUs). Make sure the GPU you're comparing with your own has support for one or both of these technologies, as this can significantly speed up encoding tasks.

**GPU Memory (VRAM)**

Video encoding is almost always a memory-intensive task, especially when working with HD and 4K material. A GPU with higher VRAM will be able to handle larger video files and store more frames in advance - thus increasing your encoding efficiency.

**CUDA Cores (NVIDIA) or Stream Processors (AMD)**

Without getting too technical, imagine this as the "Processing Power" of the GPU. The number of CUDA cores (NVIDIA) or stream processors (AMD) in a GPU will determine its processing power. A GPU with more cores/processors will be more capable of handling parallel processing tasks, which is important for faster video encoding.

There are other factors involved such as Clock Speed, Generation/Architecture and specific drivers, but when comparing old cards vs new, it's the three main points above that you want to mainly focus on over everything else, that is if you don't want to dive too deep into GPU computer science.

A common site used for comparing GPU detailed specs and general market price is [Technical City](https://technical.city/en/video).

NVIDIA Quadro series cards are a popular choice for professional post production facilities.

Comment: Are you sure about Avidemux using CUDA? I can only find various posts on their forums about it using NVENC based encoding such as https://avidemux.org/smif/index.php?topic=19584.0 and that means using the fixed function hardware encoder (fixed performance) rather than the GPU shaders which would provide a solution that scaled with GPU power...